# Storing and reading a high volume of small elements concurrently in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading, concurrency, hashset

**In short**

Lots of small Byte arrays need to be checked if they have already been seen, if not store them and move to the next batch. This happens concurrently. HashSet does wonders but completely collapses when elements exceed 1 million (every array can spawn 0, 1 or n more successors). We are not interested in deleting elements, only keeping track. What data structure is flexible enough, with good performance and usable by multiple threads?

**Longer**

For this project we are required to store a lot of byte arrays of certain states, in order to keep track of what arrays we have seen and which not. The project is done in C# with the help of the .NET framework. The actual program is a console application. The challenge is to make a single threaded reference solution a faster multi-threaded one.

Originally they were using a Trie data structure for storing all previous states, but we found it to perform poorly when using multiple threads. Instead we now use a [HashSet](https://archive.is/MnmRY) with a simple lock in case we want to write to it. We found it to work extremely well with [this](https://archive.is/MnmRY) FNV hashing function, "Fowler/Noll/Vo (FNV) 32-bit hash function". Extremely well being performance gains of around 300% over the single threaded reference implementation.

The worst case scenario at which this fails is:

- 66 million byte arrays are considered
- 7.4 million end up in our HashSet (the rest are dupes)
- That makes 7 million hashes of small byte arrays versus 66 million checks whether an array has been considered before (by hashing them and checking if that hash exists already).

**Edit**
We tried the collections in System.Collections.Concurrent, the problem is the performance we get with most of them. Some offer too much, others too little. Ideally we only store the unique hash, so that we do not end up with 7 million byte arrays. That is why we use HashSet, it has incredible performance for this application but slows down a lot when the additions grow exponentially.

**Some actual running data:**

- Considered 7001535 byte arrays, found 977689 duplicates and added 6023846 to the HashSet (2nd most complicated).
- Considered 66478557 byte arrays, found 7460501 duplicates and added 59018056 to the HashSet (worst case).

Using HashSet this yields the following results for both scenarios mentioned above:

- Elapsed time 2017 ms
- Elapsed time 17010 ms

So we roughly did 9.49 times as much work in 8.43 times as much time, that is some okay scaling (a little less than linear). Not enough though.

Using ConcurrentDictionary (value is a byte 0) we get these results:

- Elapsed time 2898 ms
- Elapsed time 32155 ms

Using ConcurrentBag we get these results:

- Terminated after 40000 ms
- Did not bother

HashSet is the clear winner in this case. Some more runs:

- Considered 704 byte arrays, found 85 duplicates and added 619 to the HashSet: Elapsed time 799 ms
- Considered 9931 byte arrays, found 1183 duplicates and added 8748 to the HashSet; Elapsed time 294 ms
- Considered 3890 byte arrays, found 603 duplicates and added 3287 to the HashSet; Elapsed time 319 ms
- Considered 64 byte arrays, found 8 duplicates and added 56 to the HashSet; Elapsed time 288 ms

Important to know when looking at these numbers is that the generation of Successors can be unsuccessful (hah). The above situations are designed to find possible errors in our program.

Comment: Since I am limited in the link count I am allowed to post, if you're interested in some more context around the assignment there is a reference implementation available here:
http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/b3cc/Prak/Rushhour.cs (Single threaded, using a Trie structure to keep track of seen states)

Yes it is an assignment for University, no I am not asking you to do my homework, just some pointers in the right direction (as we already did the BFS parallelisation ourselves)

Comment: What about a System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hint: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460718(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ^^^ That was the first link in Google btw. You should really learn how to use it.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll We actually use that to store our successor byte arrays (to look at as the next batch). Trying the bag for this purpose made it slower than the HashSet. Do you mean storing the hashes of the byte arrays in the bag? That might actually be fast enough, but FNV isn't exactly a perfect hashing algorithm (250 collisions approx on 700k byte arrays hashes).

Comment: @FirebladeDan I'm not sure what gave you the idea we did not try that ourselves. ConcurrentDictionary is often offered as a concurrent hash table (nice), but it is really a lot slower. With perfect hashing the value bit of it is quite redundant too. ConcurrentBag didn't work well, the advantage of using a Trie in this case was so that you did not have to store every singly byte array, but I might try storing the hashes as I mentioned above.

Comment: I'm sure you've tried this, but have you tried storing a `byte` as the value in your ConcurrentDictionary? I can't say whether or not you will notice any performance difference, but it may. Other than doing this, I'm not sure you're going to find any built-in .net collections that will perform any faster than a locked hashset.

Comment: Mmmm you should get the same performance from a Hashtable as a Dictionary.... It's the same thing under the covers.

Comment: You say HashSet "completely collapses when elements exceed 1 million", but then you say that its performance is "a little less than linear" with >7 million elements. Can you explain what you mean by "completely collapses"?

Comment: Is there a limit to the length of these byte arrays?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Strictly speaking? No, which is where our hashing will fail eventually. In practice we are looking at arrays ranging from 2 to 9 in length.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Regarding the collapsing: After some point it seems to exceed the single threaded solution. It slows down from 448% faster, to 365%, to 57% faster (so that's slower). When we get more and more complex this multi-threaded solution gets decimated by the single-threaded one, most likely due to the Trie present in the single-threaded variant. This could mean that the single-threaded is relatively faster in all situations. Using a profiler the majority of time clearly is spend on testing these byte arrays for uniqueness (both single and multi-threaded solutions).

Comment: So it's not that the HashSet itself is going slower, but the Trie ends up having better performance as the collision rate increases, whereas HashSet's performance stays pretty constant? Am I understanding that correctly? Do you think you could improve the Trie's multi-threading performance by only locking on the node that you're planning to add to, rather than the whole structure? Since you'd have a reduced likelihood of lock collisions, a [SpinLock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinlock.aspx) might be faster than a normal lock at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, a HashSet sounds like a good match for what you're trying to do, but .NET's implementation has a fatal flaw: it doesn't let you set your initial capacity. (Unlike, for example, C++'s `ordered_set`, which lets you specify a bucket count at construction). So a large percentage of your time is being spent rehashing as you repeatedly hit the collection's capacity. Strange that they don't let you do this, since comments in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs.html#e068afbcd77375f8) indicate that resizing hurts.

So let's measure how much the resizing/rehashing is hurting you (using 8-byte arrays with a rough approximation of your worst case):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int COUNT = 66478557;
    const int UNIQUE_COUNT = 59018056;

    // create a bunch of 8-byte arrays:
    var arrays = new List<byte[]>(COUNT);
    for (long i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i)
        arrays.Add(BitConverter.GetBytes(i % UNIQUE_COUNT));

    // the HashSet we'll be abusing (i'll plug in a better comparer later):
    var hs = new HashSet<byte[]>(EqualityComparer<byte[]>.Default);
    //var hs = new HashSet<byte[]>(new ByteArrayComparer());

    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i)
        hs.Add(arrays[i]);
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("New HashSet: " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

    // clear the collection (doesn't reset capacity):
    hs.Clear();

    // Do the adds again, now that the HashSet has suitable capacity:
    sw.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i)
        hs.Add(arrays[i]);
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Warmed HashSet: " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
}
```

I show an almost 2x speedup on a "warmed-up" hashset that has sufficient capacity:

```
New HashSet: 27914.5131
Warmed HashSet: 17683.5115
```

(That's on a Intel NUC running a laptop-grade i5, by the way.)

Ok, now let's speed up the hash implementation:

```
class ByteArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<byte[]>
{
    public int GetHashCode(byte[] obj)
    {
        long myLong = BitConverter.ToInt64(obj, 0);
        // just XOR's upper and lower 4 bytes:
        return myLong.GetHashCode();
    }

    private EqualityComparer<byte[]> _defaultComparer = EqualityComparer<byte[]>.Default;
    public bool Equals(byte[] a1, byte[] a2)
    {
        return _defaultComparer.Equals(a1, a2);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
New HashSet: 5397.449
Warmed HashSet: 2013.0509
```

...for an even bigger win!

So is there any way your app can do some sort of warmup like this on your collection? Otherwise you might want to consider creating/finding a HashSet implementation that allows you to configure your initial capacity.

Comment: I think this is one way of addressing the problem. In the end I think our solution is inherently flawed; a Trie structure will scale better without any warming up. Indeed if we know the workload, or a good prediction of it, the HashSet is way faster. In our case we don't really know anything about upcoming input. Once we got the input we can make an educated guess, but these puzzles can be very deceiving (small size, high complexity and vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the distribution of your data, you might consider retaining the Trie approach, but partition based on the first byte (or some other better-distributed byte, using some reordering to put it 'first' in the Trie), with a separate lock for each value of the 'partition byte'.  This will greatly reduce lock contention if your byte of choice is well distributed, as most of the time your various threads will be accessing different independent Tries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We currently employ a Breadth-first search, so in essence that should help a lot. The batch of successors we handle at a time are all equally far iterations from the starting situation (equal steps from the root essentially). In practice however the HashSet is almost 2 times as fast, except for that last case where the ammount of processed elements goes nuclear. I will look at the Trie reference code tomorrow again and update my post accordingly. We could have looked over something.

Comment: Hashing is probably faster than the Trie for smallish sets, as you get better memory locality while computing the hash and perform fewer comparisons/dereferences.  Obviously this breaks down as you start to fill up your hash buckets, with more collisions and increasingly frequent full-array comparisons required.  Another option would be to compute a hash, create your own buckets based on the hash, then keep a Trie in each bucket.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. We were running into a performance roof with the Trie that we didn't really have any ideas for, so instead we moved to hashing which proved promising but ultimately lacking. With the concurrent Trie we got around 150% performance increase, but we're really looking for 200% or more. So your tip here may prove invaluable, hadn't thought of it myself to combine both of them.